# How to flatten a multilevel xml into List<String xpath > in java?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jaxb, key-value

the objective is to flatten a multilevel repeated xml into xpaths at a leaf level ; so that we can store it in a Key-Value store and retrieve it . The assumption is that every repeating node will have a UID.

1. generate a list of  pairs where the Key is a "XPATH" and Values are the actual value of that leaf
2. Should be able to assemble it back into an xml
3. the xml is backed by an xsd ( is there a JAXB solution )

### Edited and replaced the previous xml with a simpler one.

a sample xml looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cars>
    <car uid="WxiMr123">
        <carDoor uid="WRP2">
            <location uid="loc-1">
                <width uom="ft">2</width>
                <height uom="ft">3</height>
            </location>
            <location uid="loc-2">
                <width uom="m">5</width>
                <height uom="m">7</height>
            </location>
        </carDoor>
        <commonData>
            <timeCreated>2001-04-30T08:15:00.000Z</timeCreated>
        </commonData>        
    </car>    
</cars>
```

The xpath K,V pairs I'm looking at should look like

```
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]@uid , "WxiMr123"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]@uid, "WRP2"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-1"]@uid, "loc-1"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-1"]/width[@uom="ft"]@uom, "ft"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-1"]/width[@uom="ft"]/text(), "2"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-1"]/height[@uom="ft"]@uom, "ft"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-1"]/height[@uom="ft"]/text(), "3"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-2"]@uid, "loc-2"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-2"]/width[@uom="m"]@uom, "m"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-2"]/width[@uom="m"]/text(), "5"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-2"]/height[@uom="m"]@uom, "m"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-2"]/height[@uom="m"]/text(), "7"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/commonData/timeCreated/text(), "2001-04-30T08:15:00.000Z"
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: "*Should be able to assemble it back into an xml*" Why don't you provide an example of what the output should look like after processing the XML input shown above. Or perhaps pick a simpler example to demonstrate. -- See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223523/xslt-nested-to-flat-structure-of-xml/24223720#24223720

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26978244/how-to-create-template-to-match-based-upon-an-xslt-parameter/26982656#26982656

Comment: Why not just store it as xml if that is the representation you want?

Comment: Brett, There is a requirement the incoming updates might not be a full xml but just a node. Therefore we avoid any read-update-write cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Producing the required document is not that difficult. For example, the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//text() | //@*[string()]">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('/', name())" />
                <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('[@', name(), '=&quot;', ., '&quot;]')" />
                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="name()">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('/@', name())" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>/text()</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(', &quot;', ., '&quot;&#10;')" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your example input, will produce the following **result**:

```
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/@uid, "WxiMr123"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/@uid, "WRP2"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-1"]/@uid, "loc-1"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-1"]/width[@uom="ft"]/@uom, "ft"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-1"]/width[@uom="ft"]/text(), "2"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-1"]/height[@uom="ft"]/@uom, "ft"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-1"]/height[@uom="ft"]/text(), "3"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-2"]/@uid, "loc-2"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-2"]/width[@uom="m"]/@uom, "m"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-2"]/width[@uom="m"]/text(), "5"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-2"]/height[@uom="m"]/@uom, "m"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/carDoor[@uid="WRP2"]/location[@uid="loc-2"]/height[@uom="m"]/text(), "7"
/cars/car[@uid="WxiMr123"]/commonData/timeCreated/text(), "2001-04-30T08:15:00.000Z"
```

**Note**:

1. This may not be the most efficient method; with large XMl documents it might be better to apply template/s to traverse the entire tree recursively;
2. Elements may have multiple attributes; your example does not show how to handle these when building the paths;
3. Elements may be in namespaces; your example does not show how to handle these;
4. Empty nodes are excluded; if you try to reconstruct the original XML document from the result of this transformation (not that I have any idea how one would go about that), these nodes will be missing.

Comment: Michael thanks a lot. Exactly what I wanted. I'm not too much worried as these xml's are going to be small ( in KB's max about 10 MB ) and not too deep.

Comment: (1) Multiple Attributes
<carRoof uid="roof">
 <carRoofName namingSystem="EPSG" code="5106">Moon Roof</carRoofName>
</carRoof>

Should look like - I think we are good here
/carRoof[@uid="roof"]/carRoofName[@namingSystem="EPSG"]@namingSystem, "EPSG"
/carRoof[@uid="roof"]/carRoofName[@namingSystem="EPSG"]@code, "5106"
/carRoof[@uid="roof"]/carRoofName[@namingSystem="EPSG"]/text(), "Moon Roof"
But yes I would like to have empty nodes as empty strings.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, it's unreadable - edit your question instead. In any case, I believe you have enough there to finish this on your own, don't you? I only meant to show a "proof of concept", so to speak.

Comment: Thanks Michael, points well taken and yes the backbone served its purpose